# Send data out from GNU Radio companion to other software via TCP/LAN protocol

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I am new to GNU Radio and Linux.

I want to send processed data out from gnu companion to a software/dashboard whose input is LAN/TCP/IP.
I am using RTL dongle and USRP and i have done GMSK demodulation successfully.Now want to send the demodulated data to a software for presentation and display developed by another team.The dashboard/software uses Ethernet data as input and has ip address and port as input parameters.

Currently i failed to send a random data via TCP sink and receive it via TCP source blocks on loopback address.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the TCP Sink to "Server", and the Source Block to "Client"? Only the block that is set to "Client" needs to know the address, but both need to know the Port.

And is the port you use for your loopback test free, or could another program be using it?

Also, if the Nonblocking mode for the TCP blocks is off, the execution of the flowgraph is halted until a connection is established. I’m not sure but I think that could lead to problems if they are supposed to connect to each other in the same flowgraph.
Try using an external program (like netcat) for debugging instead. netcat will probably not display it correctly but it’ll tell you if any data at all is coming through.

Additionally, the TCP source and TCP sink blocks are deprecated and shouldn’t be used, use UDP or ZeroMQ for communicating with external programs instead, if possible.